# Intellij Maven cannot resolve my dependency

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-3

I add my maven dependency as compile, runtime or test but it remains unresolved

This is for Intellij idea verison 2019, Java 8 and Maven 3.6.0

Error -> cannot find symbol

[image]

Comment: Is it a multi-module maven project?

Comment: It isn't a multi-module. Is a mocroservice and the dependency is a common jar in other module

Comment: have you tried `mvn clean install` ? Sometimes updating the project or reimporting project fixes dependency issues. (considering you have added it in maven `pom.xml`)

Comment: yes, mvn clean install not found -> error cannot find symbol in compilation

Comment: I try Invalidate cashes / restart but not found

Comment: have you build the project `findtome` (by `mvn clean install`) ? If so, check it once whether `findtome` directory existi in `.m2` folder or not.

Comment: yes i build with mvn clean install and existe in .m2/repository/com/.......jar

Comment: i have tried to update in intellij the local repository etc....

Comment: If it fails with maven clean install as well, it has nothing to do with intellij. My guess is that maven can't resolve the class since it is inside the BOOT-INF-folder.

Comment: Can you build it from IDE (Build | Rebuild Project)? Can you build it from command line by Maven? Do you have this dependency listed among module dependencies in [Dependencies tab](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/dependencies.html)?

Comment: I cant build it from IDE and command line. I have the dependency in dependencies tab

Comment: how to avoid this in the BOOT-INF folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependency you are trying to depend on is a runnable Spring Boot archive. These are not intended to be used as dependencies. From the Spring Boot doc (might be an older version):

> Like a war file, a Spring Boot application is not intended to be used
>   as a dependency. If your application contains classes that you want to
>   share with other projects, the recommended approach is to move that
>   code into a separate module. The separate module can then be depended
>   upon by your application and other projects.

Comment: Thanks, but how create a separated module for my shared classes ?

Comment: You could for instance move it to a submodule. This might be a good place to start: https://www.mkyong.com/maven/maven-how-to-create-a-multi-module-project/